# Caching data on Hadoop worker nodes

Tags: caching, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce, ehcache

My Map/Reduce program is requesting files frequently from S3. In the reducer, I am requesting files from Amazon S3 very frequently and the I may request the same file multiple times (about 10 K files each file is between 1 MB to 12 MB). Using Hadoop Distributed Cache is not efficient because it will copy all these files to all worker nodes (as I understand), but I don't want to do these as in the reducer phase, I may request 1000 files only from 10 K files. Moreover, if the reducer requested before a file, I don't want to request it again if the reducer needed it again. I am asking if anyone implemented a caching framework like ehcache or oscache on the worker nodes ? or are there any methods to cache only the requested files on the worker machines disks ?

Thanks
Yahia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [SHARK](http://shark.cs.berkeley.edu/)
it should not take much time to configure. Another option is memcached .

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a mature in-memory data grid with partitioned cache support. GridGain is one of them. Take a look [www.gridgain.com](http://www.gridgain.com)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use HDFS as a cache. S3 is usually much slower then local disks, so HDFS can be considered as local cache. 
I am not aware about fully automatic solution, but I believe that distcp will be of help. (http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.19.2/distcp.html) It has "update" option so it will not copy files who's size does not changed 
.